# Python, Flask WTF : token missing in session

Tags: python, session, flask, cookies, flask-wtforms

I have :

- Backend python Flask API
- React front-end (with axios for requests)

This is my backend code for CSRF :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect, generate_csrf

app = Flask(__name__)
CSRFProtect(app)
CORS(app)

@app.after_request
def inject_csrf_token(response):
    csrf_token = generate_csrf()
    response.set_cookie('csrf_token', csrf_token)
    return response
```

Front-end code :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const API_URL = `https://${window.location.hostname}:7000/v2/`;

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': Cookies.get('csrf_token')
    }
});

export default api;
```

as you can see, when I POST request to my API, CSRF Token is here :

> X-CSRF-Token:
> IjNhM2YxY2ZhNDcyYzMzZDFlZjhlMWExYmMzMWNmNTI3NzFhNDhkMjki.X9Ce-Q.E_5se2uLaCaQDAiYUOMZ4kVNtBs

But I'm getting this response :

> 400 Bad Request The CSRF session token is missing.

The issue seems to be in flask session : when I'm debugging `session` object from flask, token is present :

[image: Session contains token in flask after_request handler]

But is is empty in Flask WTF CSRFProtect code

[image: Session empty in CSRFProtect code from Flask-WTF]

I'm using Flask-WTF==0.14.3

Any help to solve this session issue would be appreciated